# How can I trigger spring batch execution from vuejs

Tags: spring, vue.js, spring-batch, execution

I am trying to trigger a spring batch execution from endpoint. I have implemented a service at the backend. So from Vue i am trying make a call to that endpoint.

```js
async trigger(data) {
    let response = await Axios.post('')
    console.log(response.data.message)
}
```

My service at the backend returns a response " Batch started" and does execution in the background since it is async but does not return back once job is executed(i see the status only in console). In such scenario how can i await the call from vue for the service execution to complete. I understand that service send no response once execution is complete/failed. Any changes i need to make either at the backend or frontend to support this. Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

It's like you said, the backend service is asynchronous, which means that once the code has been executed, it moves to the next line. If no next line exits, the function exists, the script closes, and the server sends an empty response back to the frontend.

Your options are:

1. Implement a websocket that broadcasts back when the service has been completed, and use that instead.
2. Use a timeout function to watch for a flag change within the service that indicates that the service has finished its duties, or
3. Don't use an asynchronus service

Comment: My service initiates the process at start and send response "Job started" and moves for further execution in the background where no response is delivered by service at present and that is how the implementation is. So i cannot touch the backend service

Comment: If you cannot touch the backend service then you cannot make any adjustments here to support your request.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into backend with these options

Answer (score 0):

> how can i await the call from vue for the service execution to complete

I would not recommend that since the job may take too long to complete and you don't want your web client to wait that long to get a reply. When configured with an asynchronous task executor, the job launcher returns immediately a job execution with an Id which you can inspect later on.

Please check the [Running Jobs from within a Web Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer) for more details and code examples.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you should make the front-end query for the job status instead of waiting for the job to complete and respond because the job may take very long to complete.

Your API to trigger the job start should return the job ID, you can get the job ID in the `JobExecution` object. This object is returned when you call `JobLauncher.run`.

You then implement a Query API in your backend to get the status of the job by job ID. You can implement this using the Spring `JobExplorer`.

Your front-end can then call this Query API to get the job status. You should do this in an interval (E.g. 30 secs, 5 mins, .etc depending on your job). This will prevent your app from stuck in waiting for the job and time-out errors.